# a secret to lead; a secret to leading

Tags: modifiers

> What is the **secret to your success**? ([Merriam-Webster’s Learner’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/secret))

I’ve not found an example that *secret* is modified by *to infinitive*. So I’m not sure if this sentence would be accepted: ‘*I’ll introduce a secret to **lead** your life into success*.’ - not using ***leading***.

Comment: Either one would be fine: "…a secret [that you can use] to lead your life…" or "…a secret to (gerund:) leading your life…". Note that "the secret" would be more common than "a secret".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Secret **to tell***; *secret **to share***, *secret **to protect*** and many such examples are found in COCA with a wild search of 'secret to'. It looks okay to me.

Considering *secret* as a *key* will be helpful. Both are nouns and used in such context. I don't find anything wrong with your example of introducing *a secret*.

So, to answer your question, yes, it's accepted. However, I may not prefer the word *introduce*. I may use *get you* or *tell you* or something like that. *Introducing a secret* sounds a *bit* weird. But that's just me!